# Python sys.excepthook works only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, sys

I have python server that is massive and unexcepting turning it off, or interupting without saving data is bad idea.
I found sys.excepthook function and add it so there will be no way to acidently interupt program wih Ctrl+C, but
after first exception I use Ctrl+C or any other exepction it will like doesn't care about that and predent it doesn't
exists.

Code:

```
import time
import sys


def my_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    if exctype == KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("WARNING: CTRL+C WAS PRESSED!")
        main_loop()
    else:
        sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)


def main_loop():
    print("starting!")
    while True:
        print("tick")
        time.sleep(1)


sys.excepthook = my_except_hook
main_loop()
```

Exception after second Ctrl+C:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 8, in my_except_hook
    main_loop()
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 17, in main_loop
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main_loop()
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 17, in main_loop
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Full output:

```
starting!
tick
tick
WARNING: CTRL+C WAS PRESSED!
starting!
tick
tick
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 8, in my_except_hook
    main_loop()
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 17, in main_loop
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main_loop()
  File "C:\some\path\that\you\dont\have\to\known\except_test.py", line 17, in main_loop
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I am trying to sys.exeptionhook works multiple times.